# Are empty constructors called in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

Given an empty constructor such as:

```
internal C()
{
}
```

Is it called upon object creation? It should only contain a return operation, so in theory, it could be discarded, right?

Note: It is clear to *me*, that for each class, an implicit constructor exists. The intend of this question is however; if the CLR calls constructors with exclusively a `return` operation.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be called?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - I don't assume that it shouldn't be called by definiton, but I suspect optimization.

Comment: Every layer throughout the hierarchy of an object requires a constructor to be called. If you don't do it explicitly, it will be done for you.

Comment: The C# compiler will emit the IL to call it, but the JITter may optimize it out.

Comment: What is the reason behind this question? Are you cleaning code? Are you asking from a C# spec-perspective?

Comment: What does "if the CLR calls constructors with exclusively a return operation" mean?

Comment: @flindeberg - I currently have a type with a factory method, and a constructor as displayed in the question. If empty constructors are indeed called, then the factory method may be excessive, given that 2 methods are called for initialization instead of 1.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - It indicates any constructor which is immediately determined to terminate.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel A constructor is implemented as a method which as it's first argument takes an instance of "itself", and later returns the same instance of "itself", with hopefully some instanciation done before returning. You don't see this in the `C#` code though. From a technical perspective the instance is created before the constructor is called, and therefore an empty constructor is one with "exclusively a `return` operation".

Comment: @flindeberg: do you have any material on that subject handy I can read up on? I'm interested in how a constructor is translated at that level.

Comment: @toplel32 Is the extra call an issue? The JITter probably optimizes it away if it is empty anyhow unless you run debug code. And why is the factory method residing on the type it creates? :-)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This msdn reference has a quite good description of the newobj-opcode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, it's the same as LucasTrzesniewski is referring to. For more information read the C# spec (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) and just Google your way forward :-)

Comment: @flindeberg - Peculiar semantics. The type in case serves as a container for a limited variety of objects, with only one important field such as `internal object value;`. So any object which participates in initialization, is not explicitly definitive. So unless a constructor such as `ctor(object)` deems necessary, I find constructors counter-intuitive.

Comment: @toplel32 I would say it then goes down to a design issue, I would personally prefer private constructors and public factory-methods, and not remove the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

A constructor is *always* called on object instantiation, even if it's parameterless and empty. If you don't write any constructor, a default one is implicitly generated for you by the compiler.

This is to give you the possibility to write a constructor *later on*, without having to recompile any calling code.

Object instantiation always calls a constructor for this reason, except for edge cases like [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) which is the only way I know of to instantiate an object without calling a constructor (it's used for serialization purposes).

By the way, the [`newobj`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj.aspx) IL opcode (which is used to instantiate a new object), explicitly takes a constructor as an input parameter:

> The `newobj` instruction creates a new object or a new instance of a value type. *Ctor* is a metadata token (a methodref or methoddef that must be marked as a constructor) that indicates the name, class and signature of the constructor to call.
>
> The `newobj` instruction allocates a new instance of the class associated with *ctor* and initializes all the fields in the new instance to `0` (of the proper type) or null references as appropriate. It then calls the constructor *ctor* with the given arguments along with the newly created instance. After the constructor has been called, the now initialized object reference (type O) is pushed on the stack.

So the type to create is actually **identified by the constructor to call**, not by the type token itself, which makes a constructor mandatory.

---

Since you want to know what the JIT does, here's the disassembly of the following line in Release mode (`SomeClass` is a class with an empty default constructor):

```
var inst = new SomeClass();
```

x64:

```
000007FE95A30093  in          al,dx  
000007FE95A30094  and         byte ptr [rax-73h],cl  
000007FE95A30097  or          eax,0FFEE4014h  
000007FE95A3009C  call        000007FEF5062400  
000007FE95A300A1  mov         rbx,rax  
000007FE95A300A4  call        000007FEEC977A00
```

x86:

```
00320050  push        ebp  
00320051  mov         ebp,esp  
00320053  push        esi  
00320054  mov         ecx,28380Ch  
00320059  call        002720D4  
0032005E  mov         esi,eax  
00320060  call        72EA2578  
00320065  mov         ecx,eax  
00320067  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]  
00320069  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+2Ch]  
0032006C  call        dword ptr [eax+1Ch]
```

Ok, I'm not really fluent with assembly code, but the x64 version performs two calls. I suppose the first one is the allocation and the second one is the constructor call, but I'm not sure about that (VS won't let me go to these addresses for some reason). That third (indirected) `call` in the x86 code is a surprise to me, I don't know what it's for.

Comment: `Empty constructors are always called`? if i have constructor with parameters and explicit empty constructor, why should it be called from contructor with parameters? https://dotnetfiddle.net/fuMBYR

Comment: @ASh That's not what I meant, I got my wording wrong, I'll reword this sentence to make it clear.

Comment: This information is generally reliable, but it doesn't take JIT compilation into account. The JIT compiler could totally bend the rules of virtual instructions.

Comment: @toplel32 I've added the assembly code to the answer since you seem interested. Let's see if someone more knowledgeable in assembler than me could comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

No, the constructor should *not* be discarded because it's seems like the author of the class intended it to be instantiated only from within its declaring assembly (by marking the constructor as `internal`).

Comment: That could be right, but does the CLR implementation agree?

Comment: Check it yourself. You'll not be able to *create* new instances of the type outside the assembly. But external assembles would still be able to refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you don't supply one, default constructor will be implicitly called. When object is created constructor is passed with `nextobjpointer` pointing to current object reference.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is called on every object creation as it is the default constructor.You can omit it if you don't have any other parametrised constructor but if you are using other constructors you need to specify default constructor.  For more information please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you write a constructor or not. Every time you declare an object of any class will revoke a constructor.

Now you may use this constructor explicitly to get some job done.

Or you may just leave it as blank or even don't write it in the class.

Keeping blank and not writing a constructor are totally similar.